# Want to display page content after password prompt without page reload

Tags: theme-development, password, genesis-theme-framework

I'm developing a one-page theme for WordPress, using Genesis, and I'm running into an issue with password protected pages. The way I'm running with this is I'm using a query to grab all the pages and display them, similar to a blog post loop. The downside is when there is a password protected page, it prompts for the password, but when entered, it reloads the page, taking you back up to the top of the page.

What I'd like is for the page to stay at it's current position and have the protected content display. Any advice, or pointers in the right direction would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: not sure what kind of advice you are looking for. You need to do some AJAX to get the content and insert it instead of the password form. specifics will depend on your theme

Comment: Alternatively, you'll need to edit the post password form so that the action URL includes a page-anchor that matches up to the password protected post.

Answer (score -1):

maybe this could help you.

> Devise automatically redirects on sign in and sign up as long as you
>   store the location of the current page using devise's
>   store_location_for(resource).

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update

Comment: nice to know that wordpress was ported to ruby ;)

Comment: Quick read = giant mistakes.
Shame on me